# Defining a class's .click - Before element has the class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code:

```
$('.fam.page_edit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass('page_edit').addClass("accept");
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("ikkeskrevet").addClass("kaldt");
});

$('.fam.accept').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass('accept').addClass("add");
    alert("Debug 1.");
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("kaldt").addClass("skrevet");

});
```

The first part works fine.
The classes change, and I see no problem there. Although. When I'm trying to click it, the second time. After the class changes.
No reaction. "Debug 1" doesn't pop up, no console errors in firebug. Nothing.

Comment: You want event delegation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are adding the class dynamically, event should be delegated, otherwise as there is no element with `.fam.accept` classNames on page load, jQuery can't find/select that element.

```
$(document).on('click', '.fam.accept', function(event){
   // ...
});
```

Note that events are bound to elements not to their class names, so the first click handler is executed even when you remove the `page_edit` className. If you only what to change the classNames, you can use [**`.toggleClass()`**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method instead.

```
$('.fam.page_edit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('page_edit accept');
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The event handler doesn't attach to any elements because at the time of execution there are no elements with class `accept`. Try calling this click function after the first click event.

```
$('.fam.page_edit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass('page_edit').addClass("accept");
    $('.fam.accept').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).removeClass('accept').addClass("add");
        alert("Debug 1.");
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("kaldt").addClass("skrevet");
    });
    $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("ikkeskrevet").addClass("kaldt");
});
```